# Django admin, возможность задавать простые пароли для пользователей

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Вот я создаю в админке Джанго, пользователей, но там есть момент ПАРОЛЬ, там требования сложные (типа минимум 8 символ), как мне так сделать, чтобы можно было даже 1 символ поставить.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, поддержу. Мне кажется, можно свою форму с нуля написать, но это не django-like решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для минимальной длины будет достаточно добавить это в файл настроек:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 1,
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: а вовсе убрать пароль можно? 
или придется используя это решение переписать немного шаблон админки(убрать обязательные поля пароля)

Comment: Для того чтобы вовсе убрать пароль прийдеться переопределить модель юзера